# MongoDB field level encryption with Lambda and Atlas how to include mongocryptd

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda

I try to implement MongoDB client field level encryption with an Atlas M10 cluster and AWS lambda. As far as I understand I would need to have the mongocryptd binary in my path which. How can I bundle this binary with lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) in order to package your dependencies.
The Lambda Layer can include pure python library and binary dependencies as well.

Comment: how can I use this for the local development environment? how to install in windows for local development

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it. The MongoDB documentation includes a section on how to install the MongoDB enterprise version an Amazon Linux 2 (which in August 2020 is used for lambda containers): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-amazon-tarball/

I chose to go with tarball installation. After downloading and unpacking the archive, I copied the mongocryptd binary into my serverless project and bundled it with the lambda. Inside the lambda handler I appended the path to binary to the current $PATH, so it is executable.